# How do you find filepath of the downloadHandler in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive dataframe and I have the download handler working. I would like to access the filepath so I can reference the downloaded data without using the fileInput function. The code below works, however, I am trying to to grab the filepath so I can run a prewritten function on the downloaded csv file.

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(filename = 
function({paste(Sys.time(), ' Shiny File.csv',  sep='') },
content = function(file) {write.csv(sample_data(), 
file, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you are asking. Do you want the file path on the server of on your local machine? (And are you running your prewritten function on the server or on the local machine)

Comment: Yes, the file path on my local server. The function creates a csv file, and I would like to run a function on the newly downloaded csv file.

Comment: That's really more of a system setting than an R thing.  When I am on my PC desktop, any file I download is, by default, put into `C:\Users\[username]\Downloads`, but the default folder is bound to vary from one machine to the next (and the setting could just as easily be changed).  You can likely make a pretty good guess based on your operating system, but if you don't have access to the system settings, you may need to ask your system administrator for help.

Comment: okay, that's good to know. I know where the file path is if I manually search for it, but I will write a function to grab it then